# Is there a menu item property like "drop down is open"?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a custom control ToolStripMenuItem, and I need to know whether its drop down menu is open or not. I could not find such property, does it exist?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear, could you explain using code or something which makes your question easy to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [visible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.visible(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `ToolStripMenuItem`

Comment: Thank you very much! The property `DropDown.Visible`, in fact, was exactly what I needed.